# Why, in Angular 2, are the event attributes in parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In Angular 1, e.g. we would say inside the element, `ng-click="wasClicked()"`,
yet now we say `(click)="wasClicked()"`. Why is this? The only thought that springs to my mind is that Angular 2 doesn't have to have an attribute for every element event, i.e. anything surrounded by parenthesis will be processed, whether there is a meaningful handler for it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various point to decided `()` for events

1. `()` parenthesis for `event` make sense because Angular 2 replace almost (20) `event` A1 directive  via single syntactical sugar.
2. You can also have any customEvent name inside parenthesis `(myCustomEvent)="myHandler($event)"` (`$event` is event object).
3. By having `()` in the HTML considered to be valid HTML.

**Side Note**

As like `()` parenthesis replaces several A1 20 directives by single `()` parenthesis syntactical sugar likewise `[]` property binding also replaces `16` angular directives.

Awesome [Misko's Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dMBcqwvYA0&feature=youtu.be&t=15m) explaining why he had decided `()` for event & `[]` for property binding.

Comment: I considered adding 3. to my answer but actually it's not really relevant because `(xxx)="yyy"` will never be added to the DOM and is only processed internally by Angular.

Comment: Correct, Though its valid point, but it doesn't add (event) to DOM, angular parser does bind event behind the scene for us.

Answer (score 2):

There was a long discussion what syntax should be used. In the end `()` was decided.

In Angular2 there are no specific directives for every supported event.

```
(click)="clickHandler($event)"
```

registers the `clickHandler` method as handler for the `click` event where `click` can be any valid event name, also custom events.

Registering an handler for events that aren't emitted by any element are valid as well. As you see below you can't know in advance what events are fired anyway.

This increases flexibility a lot because new events don't need any code change or new directives.

For example you can call

```
element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('my-xxx-event', { bubbles: true }));
```

and listen using

```
(my-xxx-event)="doSomething($event)
```

without any additional work.

Comment: Yes,,as I suspected. Thanks.